# WinForm Security Context

Tags: c#, .net, security

I have written a WinForms app that uploads addresses from a spreadsheet, and geocodes them using an external geocoding service.  This all works fine on my local machine, but the time has come for it to be installed on other peoples computers for testing.  The app no longer works now though, generating the below error:

```
 System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.
```

Having read a lot and chatted breifly to our network guys, it seems i need to establish the Security Context for the users account and work with this to correct the error.

Has anyone got any pointers about how I should be going about this?

Thanks in advance!

C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how your uploading the data. If your using a http request (as it looks like you are) it will look something like;

```
  HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://test.example.com/");
  req.Method = "POST";
  req.ContentType = "text/xml";

  req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("TESTACCOUNT", "P@ssword");

  StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
  writer.Write(input);
  writer.Close();
  var rsp = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
```

Comment: Im using just WebRequest, but i see what your doing there. At the moment I set DefaultCredentials. Can I specify NetworkCredentials for each user programatically or would I have to hard code it say with my username/password as you have done in your example?

Comment: DefaultCredentials gets the security context of the user thats currently logged in. From the error it looks like you have access to upload that file and the general users dont. I personaly would create a new user account with permissions and a password that wont expire and just give it permission to upload files. You can then hardcode the username and password in your code.

Comment: Would love to do that, but our corporate it techies love locking things down!  So i think new user account would be pushing it!

Comment: Adding a new user account with just that permission is more secure than using yours. You can use yours but it will mean exposing your usename and password to the world (a simple sniffer like fiddler would get your details). Also if you use yours then every time you change password all the applications would break. The only other option would be to give the upload privilidges to every user who wants to use your account then keep using the DefaultCredentials